# Is Intel based graphic card compatible with tensorflow/GPU?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, intel, graphic

Is this graphic card compatible with tensorflow/GPU ?

```
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:44 memory:c2000000-c23fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:7000(size=64)
```

Comment: Tensorflow for GPU uses CUDA, which is only compatible with NVIDIA graphics cards.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

At the moment no. Only Nvidia GPUs and (intel/amd) CPU versions are available.

They are working on an openCL compatible version of tensorflow that would be compatible and you can follow its progress [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22)