# tensorflow GPU based installation

Tags: python, tensorflow

My system is ubuntu 16.04 version my laptop is [dell Inspiron-5521](https://www.digit.in/laptops/dell-inspiron-15r-5521-w540202in8-price-1746.html) and it has intel graphic card but tensorflow needs nvidia graphics for cuda support.

Is there any way where i can run tensorflow with GPU(with CPU is working) on intel graphics.

During installation of tensorflow-gpu i have no error when i import i get 
"

> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime

."

Did some digging then found to install cuda downloaded the "cuda_9.1.85_387.26_linux.run" file but faces issues while running it

> "Detected 4 CPUs online; setting concurrency level to 4.
>
> The file '/tmp/.X0-lock' exists and appears to contain the process ID
>
> '1033' of a runnning X server.
>
> It appears that an X server is running. Please exit X before
>   installation. If you're sure that X is not running, but are getting
>   this error, please delete any X lock files in /tmp."

Deleted files from tmp folder and tried still same issue.

Answer (score 1):

To run `tensorflow-gpu` you need nvidia card. You'll need to stick to running normal tensorflow on CPU.
[Is Intel based graphic card compatible with tensorflow/GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000518/is-intel-based-graphic-card-compatible-with-tensorflow-gpu)

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow does not support OpenCL API that you can use with Intel or AMD, only CUDA. CUDA is a proprietary NVidia technology that only works with NVidia GPUs.

You may like to search for machine learning frameworks that utilise OpenCL, but I only find some niche projects at the moment.

I had to switch from AMD to NVidia to be able to run Tensorflow calculations on GPU.